# Suggestions on linking my fat static libraries to a new static library that i am creating in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, libraries

Im creating a static library(x.a) that heavily depends on many other static libraries (abc_1.a, abc_2.a, ... abc_n.a). I can build it with no problems at all, but when i use my generated x.a library to a new project it results to a lot of linker errors, most of it pointing to abc_1.a - abc_n.a, can i ask for suggestions or tips on what i missed?

**things i already tried**

- in x.a, i copied all abc and x headers to my "copy headers" in build phases
- in x.a, i added all my abc libraries in "Link binary with libraries" in build phases
- I'm sure my libraries are fat for both simulator and device.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. >//<

Comment: Miu:  Edit your question to show what you learned in your research or how you were able to fix your issue.  If you have not resolved your issue then add more information to your initial question.I'm trying to do something similar.  Perhaps we can help each other.  With more information, I can upvote your question.  This is a good question, because a lot of people are having trouble since Apple updated Xcode and iOS.  It was probably down voted because of a lack of information.

Answer (score 0):

If your static library A depends on static libraries B, C and D then you will have to add A, B, C and D to the linker phase of the resulting app.

The static library itself will not link (include) the other static libraries that it references. They all have to be put together in the resulting app.

Comment: Do you mean that when I create my app that will use x.a and its headers i will also add the abc_1.a, abc_2.a, ... abc_n.a libraries and their headers?

Comment: Yup, that's what you need to do.